# An X x X Slitherlink related to X

Tags: cipher, grid-deduction, slitherlink

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #13: Variety Slitherlinks](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/monthly-topic-challenge-13-variety-slitherlinks).</sub>

---

The final answer is a six letter word.
Prefer no partial answers.
[image: slitherlink]
[penpa](https://swaroopg92.github.io/penpa-edit/#m=solve&p=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&a=RZRdCsMwDIPvsuc+NHKan7OM3f8a+7woGRQshCzbRe37/bnyeamUS0VXeV0L6zEWfBgHfDfu8OOPoxgP+Gk84d2Ln9SM26V6G9Nb3avUbx5c3Qt3/IN9tmfias9IvXsTP9bgrce34KfH+9eKfvPgx7fA6fH+eKvZs3JX3Ty4+V3BqXkWM9Xsz0w165l5/PFWtx5vNd9FPZ74qdsHP42tyV7vQ1U3T1V3L/X4d+7qvjHx8A5w6n5vVM3tyaxpT2Zq2JOqaf1gt1H/eHpPOA3Pomr6dmbGbR/mHP+ZGnuC47YevyB/C0/wuiXuG83if7isHZKLsubmnLi3PsBbU9Gs23NOyBrmhDOfNZzPnHn88Y6y+XaF85l+Qf5+GL+Q9dTwt5P1eJLzkHdI7MwnF2R9YXbb/uT9+Cd2VrMvnOcgz0F2D3a2kwvnLfvC30jWcJ7TIx7z1NNLXzj/WZd+/STy+XwB)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The slithelink seems to be impossible.
To fix that issue you need to ...

> Ignore the green lines.  They are not part of the solution.
>   If you do that and you use the fact that green lines are not part of the path, you can solve the slitherlink.

> [image]

Step 2

> Look at the green rectangles, look at the lines in and bordering these rectanges, including the original green lines, they spell "PIGPEn".

> Pigpen is a traditional cipher that encodes the alphabet in partially drawn squares.  Possibly with a dot in the center.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher
>
>   Notice that some of the yellow squares contain a dot.
>   The lines bordering the yellow squares with the dots form pigpen letters.  They spell "DIALPAD".

Step 3

> The red squares seem to use a similar code as the yellow squares.
>   But they spell "DDAIFH".  Not very convincing.

> If you replace the "hash" figure of the pigpen alphabet with a dialpad, you get 441968.  Or, if you read the corresponding letters,
>     [ghi][ghi][ ][wxyz][mno][tuv].
>
>  If I take 1 as a space, I can make up "HI YOU".
>
>  Unfortunately that is not a 6-letter word.  A 6-character solution at most.
>  Even so, the answer "hi, you!" looks a bit awkward.  So, well, I must be missing something.
>
>  There are variations on the letters on dialpads with letters on the 1 key but I couldn't find one that yields a meaningful word.

Update and conclusion

> The title "An X x X Slitherlink related to X" means a 10x10 slitherlink.  But stresses that the solution has to do with X somehow.

Stiv noted that

> 441968 could be a date, 4.4.1968, which happens to be the date of Marting Luther King's assassination.
>  He ventures the X is then a reference to Malcolm X.
>  While this is intriguing, it ends up being a coincidence.

Then SeptaCube cracked the last step:

> "If you just consider the number of surrounding segments [of the red cells] you can get 332233, which uniquely translates to DECADE [on a dialpad]."
>
>  X is 10 in roman numerals, referring to the 10 years in a decade.
>
>  This solution was confirmed by the Puzzle setter.

Comment: An idea: note that your numeric string resembles rot13(N qngr. Sbhegu bs ncevy avargrra fvkgl rvtug, gur qngr bs gur nffnffvangvba bs ZYX, n pvivy evtugf npgvivfg jvgu fvzvynevgvrf gb Znypbyz K (bs gur gvgyr). Guhf gur nafjre pbhyq or ZNEGVA...)

Comment: This is not the right #... Less complicated.

Comment: rot13(Vs lbh whfg pbafvqre gur ahzore bs fheebhaqvat frtzragf lbh pna trg 332233, juvpu havdhryl genafyngrf gb QRPNQR.)

Comment: @SeptaCube Which fits perfectly since the slitherlink's size is 10x10.

Comment: Yep @SeptaCube has found it.

Comment: I propose to edit SeptaCube's answer into the solution.